# why processing 'optimize sort' takes less time than normal sort?

Tags: sorting, optimization

As Everybody know that processing a sort who is optimize takes less time than normal sort? After knowing that optimize a sort takes less time, first thought that comes to my mind is "What makes is Faster"?

Comment: By the definition of "optimized", I guess.. It's not really clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason an optimized sort runs faster is that it reduces the number of times two elements are compared and/or moved.

If you think about a naive worst-case sort of N items, where you compare each of the N items to each of the N-1 other items, there is a total of N*(N-1)=N^2-N comparisons. One possible way of optimizing the process would be to sort a smaller list - say N/2. That would take N/2*(N/2-1) comparisons, or N^2/4-N/2. But of course, you would have to do that on both halves of the list, which would double that - so N^2/2-N comparisons. You would also need N/2 additional comparisons to merge the two halves back together, so the total number of comparisons to sort two half-sized lists and merge them back together would be N^2/2-N+N/2, or N^2/2-N/2 - half the number of comparisons for sorting the whole list. Recursively subdividing your lists down to 2 items that can be sorted with just one comparison can provide significant savings in the number of comparisons. There are other divide-and-conquer ideas as well as ways to exploit discovered symmetries in the lists to help optimize the sorting algorithm, and coupled with the different ways to arrange data in memory (arrays vs linked lists vs heaps vs trees.... etc.) this leads to different optimized algorithms.